# Custom message at the end of Yeoman generate

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

After everything is done, I want to show a custom message to the user. I tried to write an `end` function but that does not get called.

I [did ask this](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/559#issuecomment-43594663) in the Yeoman repo, but they said it's more suited for SO.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing something like this?

Remember to use this.log when showing messages, and how to use priority is in the [documentation](http://yeoman.io/authoring/running-context.html)

```
module.exports = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({
    initializing: function() {
        this.fs.copy(
            this.templatePath('blah.js'),
            this.destinationPath('blah.js')
        );
    },
    end: function() {
        this.log("All Done!");
    },
});
```